# Calling first record for each user

Tags: php, mysql

i have those two databases:

users DB

```
_______________________
| ID  |   username    |
-----------------------
|  1  |    JOHN       |
|  2  |    JACKSYS    |
|  3  |    GATSBY     |
|  4  |    GERARD     |
-----------------------
```

And products to sell DB for each user.

```
_______________________
| ID  |   product     |
-----------------------
|  1  |    JACKET     |
|  1  |    SOCKS      |
|  1  |    TROUSERS   |
|  2  |    SHIRT      |
-----------------------
```

How should be my query, if i want to select the first product only from each user, taking into considerations once this product is selected, it will be deleted later and another product will be as first position for every user. Appreciate your help.

Comment: just join the tables and do a `group by product`. you'll naturally only get one product that way.

Comment: @Strawberry no his product is "socks". "John" will sell his "socks".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend having your database setup like this. You should have each item have a unique id as well as the user id. Then you could just call a mysql_query like this

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id='$userid' AND productid='1'); //Where 1 would be the first item associated with the user
```

This would also allow you to delete the item easier. However, if you don't feel like changing around your database, you can do this..
Simply do a loop through your database and break it when you have found the first item with a matching id, then use the associated data.

```
$userid = ;//Set the user id however you would like

$sqlcon = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id='$userid'"));
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($sqlcon);
for ($i=0; $i<$num_rows; $i++) {
  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlcon);
  if ($row['id'] == $userid) {
    $productname = $row['username']; // I would recommend changing this column name to product not username
    break;
  }
}

if (!empty($productname)) {
  echo $productname;
}
```

Comment: but i want to pick the username randomly, i don't think i need a FOR loop.

Answer (score 0):

To get the first product from each user you can use the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM products JOIN users ON users.id = products.id GROUP BY users.id
```

The result from this query:

```
______________________________________
| ID  |   product     |   username   |
--------------------------------------
|  1  |    JACKET     |    JOHN      |
|  2  |    SHIRT      |    JACKSYS   |
--------------------------------------
```

I renamed the username column in the products table into product.